# Workshop(s) for application to Marie Curie postdoctoral Fellowships (formerly IIF, IEF and IOF, now just IF)

Tags: job, postdocs, workshop, eu

I believe there are workshops offered to people who want to prepare application to Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowships (now part of the Individual Fellowships offered by them). I am trying to find out when the next workshop is or the general schedule of such workshops over the year.

I tried to find online information on them, without much success, I noticed some heavily charged workshops that happened before. My questions are:

1. Where can I find information and schedule of such workshops?
2. Are they always held by the authority/organization offering Marie Curie fellowships? Or, there could be other universities wanting to get Marie Curie postdocs and hence could offer a workshop?
3. Is there a "local" workshop for a region, for example, people from Spain might not want to travel to Germany etc.
4. Are there free ones, or is a fee always required?

Comment: Wholesale questions are frowned upon on SE sites, please consider dividing this question, into multiple separate questions, as they would be easier to find for others in the same situation later on.

Comment: Also note that questions should preferably be relevant for general public, and for longer time. Thus asking for when a workshop takes place, or where you can find information on workshops isn't necessarily a good question, as that information is pretty much bound to change over time, and the answers will lose relevance.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of removing the two links you put at the end of your question, because in my view they looked a little too much like advertising. :) Also, I have reworded your point 4; I hope I haven't misunderstood you. Let me know if you have objections to my edits.

Comment: Postdef: If you think, you'll clearly see that the posts are indeed relevant for a general public, of course I don't mean a first year Ph.D. The website is for academia, so people tend to do postdoc, Marie Curie is a good one, so obviously popular; in order to write a better proposal, we all need workshops. Do you see the link to general public now?

Also, I believe closely related questions like mine demand a place to be together. Note that questions will need a short answers here, so okay to ask together. If not okay with you, please cite me a rule of the community and I'll be happy to edit.

Comment: Postdef: regarding loosing relevance over time: I disagree: normally places where workshops are held increase over time, so the answers will still apply couple of years from now.

Comment: Federico: rewording point 4 is okay, removing the two links is not. I didn't intend to advertise anything, just wanted to give a clear idea through examples to have a better answer. Indeed, one of the workshops were heavily charged, which contradicts the view of advertisement: people don't want to pay lot of money for these kind of workshops.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, universities organise these workshops (training events) for their own faculty, possibly in collaboration with commercial companies that provide this kind of training. This is the case not only for Marie Curie fellowships, but for all kinds of EU Horizon 2020 funding opportunities.

Contact the research support people from your own university and ask if they are planning to organise such workshops. Most likely, it would be free for you. Your university would cover the expenses.